# Change the font color of abstract and acknowledgements titles?

Tags: fonts, color, titles

I have managed to change the font color of all my titles in my thesis, i.e. chapters, sections, subsections by using:

```
\definecolor{MyBlue}{RGB}{0,47,135}
\chapterfont{\color{MyBlue}}
\sectionfont{\color{MyBlue}}  
\subsectionfont{\color{MyBlue}}
```

which intuitively makes sense to me. However, the abstract and acknowledgements are separate `.tex` files, wherein I simply use the `\begin{abstract}`, indicating that I cannot change the font color directly. How would I go about this?

Comment: `\textcolor{MyBlue}{
\begin{abstract}
   abstract
\end{abstract}}`?

Comment: @marmot - That makes the text inside the abstract all blue, which I'm not interested in. It is only the title "Abstract" which needs to be blue :)

Comment: You havr to patch the definition of the abstract environment, which we don't know. It might have been implemented in a bad way.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Thank you for the clarification, I just figured it out by following your advice. I have a .cls file containing the documentclass, where I found the abstract settings. Thank you!

Comment: Please always provide an MWE with your question. In its current form we can only guess as to how your `abstract` environment is defined and the question is very unlikely to help others finding it in a web search.

Comment: If you do not want to "hack" the `abstract` settings, you can always do `\textcolor{MyBlue}{\begin{abstract}
   \textcolor{black}{This is the abstract.}
\end{abstract}}`.

Comment: You should never change a class file.